# Find out the IP or hostname of the firewall?

Tags: firewalls, nmap, netcat

Is there a way to find the IP of the firewall which is blocking my access to an endpoint?

I tried netcat / nmap but not much luck.

I need some form of a tool which does a traceroute to the subnet or IP which is blocking the access so I can know which firewall is blocking my  access to a port on an endpoint?

Comment: So like `tracert` but not with ICMP packets but TCP? You could use `hping` or `tracert`, but the firewall will probably no ICMP-errors to trace this correctly.

Comment: I've suggested to close this topic as it is not considered to be about information security.

Answer (score 1):

If the firewall is operating in transparent mode at the IP level and does not decrease the TTL of the IP packet, for example, it is not going to be possible by TCP/UDP tools to know which exact router/firewall is blocking/dropping.

You can guess that there is something that is blocking/dropping the packets but if the firewall is in transparent mode I would say that the response is 'no'.

Also consider that your connection can receive RST packets that reset the connection from any router/firewall on the path.